# Having trouble importing a database

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL for the first time but I'm running into some problems. I purchased a book called "Learning SQL" (O'Reilly).

First off, the book asked me to download mySQL v6.0. I couldn't find it and the URL in the book redirected me to a download page for mySQL Community Server 5.7. I assume this is the latest version of the same package. I downloaded the installer and installed without any problems. Is this the correct software needed?

Then I tried following the instructions for the command line input, but it didn't work out. I downloaded an example sql database, but I'm having trouble importing it. Is there a guide available to do this?

Sorry if my questions are really newbish. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5.7 is fine - although you might look at MariaDB too - I think O'Reilly were being a bit optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want learn clean SQL - without any specials of Oracle Database, PL/SQL and something like that, then you can comfortably make it with any database what you find. :-)

Basic SQL is not dependent on any database software or their version.

Edit: If you have 2005 edition - it´s really independent on any SQL server.